# A function $f$ such that $f(x)$ increases from $0$ to $1$ when $x$ increases from $0$ to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

I am looking for a function f(x) with a value range of [0,1].

f(x) should increase from 0 to 1 while its parameter x increases from 0 to +infinity.

f(x) increases very fast when x is small, and then very slow and eventually approach 1 when x is infinity.

Here is a figure. The green curve is what I am looking for:

[image]

Thanks.

It would be great if I can adjust the slope of the increase. Although this is not a compulsory requirement.

Comment: Do you want it to actually take on the values 0 and 1?

Comment: @MikeMiller value 0 yes. value 1 no. f(x)=0 when x=0, =1 when x=infinity, and = a value between 0 and 1 otherwise.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1-\frac1{x+1}$

Comment: @Leo do you want this $f$ to be $\mathcal{C}^0$? or something more strict perhaps?

Comment: It is always going to be relative fast when $x$ is small, a simple consequence of the fact that you require it to be bounded and monotone.

Comment: OP: Didn't you ask for an infinite slope at $0$?

Comment: some hyperbola should do it.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I think this should work well for your purposes:
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{x + a}
$$
Where $a$ can be any number bigger than $0$.  The smaller $a$ is, the sharper the increase will be.

**ADDENDUM:** if you want to extend this to an odd (and continuously differentiable) function, simply take
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{|x| + a}
$$

Comment: I love this function so much. So simple, elegant, and nice....

Comment: And in particular, the slope at $x=0$ is $\dfrac{1}{a}$.

Comment: I like this, but it would be great to be able to parameterise the rate of convergence to the asymptote as well as the slope at the origin.

Comment: @Keith in what sense do you mean?  Would something like $f(x) = \frac{x^n}{x^n + a}$ be sufficient for those purposes?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That $f(x)$ does not have the right gradient at $x=0$.
$$g(x) = f(x)^{1+bf(x)}$$ would do, but seems a bit ugly.

Comment: What about $$g(x) = f(e^{kx}x) = \frac{e^{kx}x}{e^{kx}x + a}?$$
It still has slope $\frac{1}{a}$ at $x=0$, and rises to $1$ quite rapidly for even modestly large values of $k$.

Comment: @Kieth take any function of the form $f(g(n))$, with $f(x) = \frac x{x+a}$ and $g$ any function that increases to infinity.  So, for example, $f(x(x+1)^n)$ will work, with out messing with the gradient at $0$.

Answer (score 21):

Here are two simple functions with slope $k$ at $x=0$, for some $k>0$:

$$f(x) = 1-e^{-kx}$$

and

$$g(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}kx\right)$$

The first of these approaches $1$ more quickly than the second.

Comment: One nice thing about the arctan version: it also approaches -1 as x approaches -infinity.

Answer (score 20):

One I use very often is :
$$ \tanh x = \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x} = \frac {e^x - e^{-x}} {e^x + e^{-x}} = \frac{e^{2x} - 1} {e^{2x} + 1} = \frac{1 - e^{-2x}} {1 + e^{-2x}}$$

The increase at the begining around 0 is "only" linear but can do the work. and you can choose the slope at $x \mapsto 0$
[image: Hyperbolic tangent]

Comment: Use $f(x) = \tanh mx$ if you want slope $m$ at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 16):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned erf(x) aka the "Error Function", defined roughly as the normalized area under the bell curve as a function of the upper limit of integration. For x > 1, it satisfies your requirement and also has a slope that is easily controlled (and made arbitrarily large at 0) by the width of your Gaussian.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted so much? The error function is in fact a sigmoid curve with limit $1$ as $x\to\infty$ and is different from the other suggestions. Perhaps the fact that it isn't an elementary function makes it less appealing, but it certainly meets the criteria in the OP.

Answer (score 8):

$f(x) = 1 - \exp(-x/\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon > 0$ small will do.

Answer (score 6):

Some time ago I had an interest in such a function, but with the added requirement that it should map negative values of $x$ onto the range $(-1,0)$, asymptotically approaching $-1$
as $x$ goes to $-\infty$.
In fact, I wanted $f(-x) = -f(x)$.

I came up with something like this:

$$ f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2 + x^2}} .$$

This has slope $\frac{1}{|a|\,}$ at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 6):

> Simple version:
>   $$f(x)=1-\mathrm e^{-a\sqrt{x}}\qquad (a\gt0)$$

Slightly more elaborate version:$$f(x)=1-\mathrm e^{-a\sqrt{x}-bx}\qquad (a\gt0,\ b\geqslant0)$$
Every such function fits every requisite in the question, including the infinite slope at $0$. The parameter $a$ can help to tune the increase near $0$. The parameter $b$ can help to tune the increase near $+\infty$. To get even quicker convergence to $1$ when $x\to+\infty$, one can replace $-bx$ in the exponent by $-bx^n$ for some $b\gt0$ and $n\gt1$.

Once one understands the principle, a host of other solutions springs to mind.

Answer (score 3):

Try $f(x) = 1-e^{-x^2}$ , which will be 0 for x = 0 and approach 1 rapidly for big x.

Comment: But doesn't increase very fast when $x$ is small.

Comment: Judging from the scale of his sketch, i thought it would be very sufficiently fast.

Comment: Look at the derivative of the function at $x = 0$. It seems the OP wants something with initially a large positive slope that gradually flattens out, not a slope that starts flat, increases, then decreases.